# Android how to stop timer when app go to background

Tags: android, android-activity

I know there are ton of questions as this have been asked in stackoverflow. Most of those suggest to implement `onResume` and `onPause` to control how the app behaves when it goes to background/foreground. But I couldn't actually use that method in my case.

I have a `timer` that will run when my application start (or after user login). So it is not dependent on any `activity` in my app. What I want to do is to stop the `timer` (to save power resource) when app goes to background and restart it when app come back to foreground. By implementing `onResume` and `onPause` will stop and start the `timer` when user switch between the `activities` (because I implemented in all the `activities`), and this is not what I wanted.

Please give advice how this to be done in better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cancel() method in onPauso() so when the app are in background you stop the timmer
In the method onResume() you launch other time your Timer.

you can see method in:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: I don't want to start and stop the timer all the time when user switch between the activities.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand you. If you want continue the Timer in background, you must start in service and not in Activity. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

extend the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and add a public static counter on it. On every `onPause()` and `OnResume()`, increment or decrement it, when the counter is zero you app is in background.